# Can I represent a "git rebase" as a series of cherry-picks?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

It seems that "git rebase" has additional fallback logic to deal with merge failures:

```
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
```

What is it doing there, and how would I need to invoke my cherry-picks to get the same behavior?

Probably the right solution is to just not attempt to represent a rebase as a series of cherry-picks, but it would be nice if this were possible, since I can then deal with both rebases and arbitrary collections of changes using the same flow.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? A graph may help.

Comment: I have a CI workflow that can either consume a rebase or a set of disparate patches. Instead of having to distinguish between the two cases, I'd rather transform the rebase into a set of cherry-picks and not have to think when doing a checkout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most `git rebase` commands actually *do* run `git cherry-pick`.

The fallback you're seeing occurs from the one form of `git rebase` that, for historical reasons, *doesn't* use `git cherry-pick`.  That one form is used when you invoke a *non*-interactive `git-rebase` *and* don't use any of the options that make it use new-and-improved rebase-invoking method.

The old form *usually* produces the same effect.  It consists of using `git format-patch` to turn each commit into a patch, and then using `git am --3way` to apply all the formatted patches.  The `--3way` option tells `git am` that, if the patch cannot be applied blindly, it should use the `index` lines in each formatted patch to achieve part of what `git cherry-pick` *would* have done automatically.

If you want rebase to use `git cherry-pick` directly, you may:

- supply the `-k` option, or
- supply the `-m` option, or
- supply a `-s strategy` option, or
- supply a `-X extended-option` option, or
- use interactive rebase (`-i` or `--interactive`), or
- use the `--autosquash` option, or
- use the `-p` or (Git 2.18+) `-r` option.

Comment: I'd rather understand how I can make my series of patches behave like a rebase. I think you gave the answer, but I'd need to code it and test it. If I understand correctly, every "cherry-pick" needs to use format-patch and git am --3way.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that I've tried applying cherry-picks one after the other, and that fails, but the rebase succeeds... but you seem to be saying that it should have succeeded...

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, then. If you have a series of patches, use `git am --3way` (or `-3` for short) to get the same effect that `git rebase` gets when it uses `git format-patch` and `git am`. Note that if you don't control the `git format-patch` operation, you'll get *abbreviated* `index` lines, which may not be useful. You want whoever generates patches to use `--full-index`. Or, if you have a series of commit hash IDs in your own repository, use `git cherry-pick` on them, one at a time, to apply them at the current `HEAD`.

Comment: Using `cherry-pick` is superior in a few ways, but also slower (because it does full-tree diffs to find renames). Note also that rebasing ends by forcing the branch label to move to the newly constructed commits; if you invoke either `git cherry-pick` or `git am` / `git apply` yourself, you have to do that yourself too.

Comment: The one remaining thing to consider is that when `git rebase` enumerates commits for `git cherry-pick` (using the cherry-pick code path), it *omits* some commits intentionally. Specifically, commits that exist in the upstream as well as the current branch, and have the same patch-ID in both "sides", get omitted; all merges get omitted unless using `-p` or `-r`, in which case they're enumerated specially so as to be repeated. The enumeration uses `git rev-list --left-right --cherry-mark <upstream>...HEAD` to figure out which commits are which.

Comment: (The above details aren't 100% accurate, sometimes there's `--no-merges` and sometimes you can get away with `--right-only`. Before recent changes to make `git rebase` all C code, it was easier to identify which rebases did which thing and what `git rev-list` command they used, as this as all several very large shell scripts.)